# Python- Allow user to modify item name in list and then show list with new name?

Tags: python, edit

the code for this part of the program is below. I'm trying to allow a user to edit the name of one of the items and then when he enters the show command in the program the updated name will be there. I'm stuck on what function to use to allow the user to edit the name. thanks

```
def edit(item_list):
   number = int(input("Number: "))
   list.insert(item)
   item = input("Updated name: ")
   print(item +"was updated")

def main():
    # this is the item list
    item_list = ["wooden staff","wizard hat","cloth shoes"]
```

so if I enter edit as my command and then I write hello for number 1 item I want it to replace wooden staff with hello.

Comment: You can't use `insert` for this because it does exactly as its English definition says. It adds a new item to the list, it doesn't replace something in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
def edit(item_list):
    pos = int(input("Number: "))    
    new_value = input("Updated name: ")
    item_list[pos-1] = new_value
    print"%s was updated" % (new_value)
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Let's say I input `0`. Then what happens?

Comment: I assume the input is an integer > 0

Comment: thanks for your input! How would I put a command in there that showed an invalid message when a user enters an invalid number to edit from?

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoRuedaFlores

Answer (score 1):

You can modify a list item by simply reassigning that index:

```
def edit(item_list):
    number = int(input("Number: "))
    curr_item = item_list[number]
    new_item = input("Updated name: ")
    item_list[number] = new_item
    print("{} was updated to {}".format(curr_item, new_item))
    return item_list

item_list = edit(item_list)
```

I am assuming that your `print` statement is meant to indicate what was changed. If you just want to re-print what the user entered, you can change it.

Comment: `item_list` is not a global variable though. How can this work unless `edit()` is called and it `return`s something?

Comment: is that the simplest way the code can be written? thanks!

Comment: @tejashpatel no because it doesn't work, in the context of your example

Comment: Edited for the return. I was not trying to fix his entire script, which currently will not work for other reasons either - such as having no way to call `edit`. I was just trying to fix the `edit` function so that it actually updated the list that was sent it.

Comment: You also need to consider your input prompt for the number: whether you expect your users to know that lists are 0-indexed or whether you need to correct for that. But like I said, I am not trying to offer an entire program re-write or fix, just to help with your specific question of editing an item of a list based on an item number provided.

Comment: I have removed my down vote because you addressed my question properly but I really think from the sample code provided that it's not a push to give a complete answer (exception handling I consider as something different, but at least the intended flow with the intended inputs...)